# how can i disable button when the user gets to the last page

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I have response in such form

```
{
  "currentPage": 1,
  "totalPages": 2,
  "totalCount": 2,
  "pageSize": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "productId": 2,
      "name": "testPorduct",
      "description": "bla bla bla",
      "price": 1000,
      "state": "new",
      "color": "sss",
      "rate": 5.5,
      "imageFileName": "ooo",
      "quantity": 10,
      "categoryId": 5
    }
  ],
  "hasPrevious": false,
  "hasNext": true
}
```

where i have hasPrevious and hasNext properties, and i need to make button disabled when property hasNext is false.

I use EventEmitter for rerendering page when user change page size or pageNumber, and on every click i make request to the server :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.restService.getProductsPaged(this.defaultPageSize, this.defaultPageNumber).subscribe(
      (data: Product) => this.products = {
        currentPage : data.currentPage,
        totalPages : data.totalPages,
        totalCount : data.totalCount,
        pageSize : data.pageSize,
        items: data.items,
        hasPrevious: data.hasPrevious,
        hasNext: data.hasNext,
      }
    )
  }
```

and for example next page :

```
next(event){
    event.preventDefault;
    this.page += 1;
    this.pageChange.emit(this.page)
    this.restService.getProductsPaged(this.pageSize, this.page).subscribe(
      (data: Product) => this.products = {
        currentPage : data.currentPage,
        totalPages : data.totalPages,
        totalCount : data.totalCount,
        pageSize : data.pageSize,
        items: data.items,
        hasPrevious: data.hasPrevious,
        hasNext: data.hasNext,
      }
    )
  }
```

my checkLastPage function

```
checkLastPage() : boolean{
    var a = this.products.hasNext;
    console.log(a);
    return !a;
  }
```

and my console.log prints me four times true or false and 'Cannot read property 'hasNext' of undefined'
How can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you might be having which says that 'Cannot read property 'hasNext' of undefined' occurs because you might not have initialized products object.

You dont need to create a separate function just to disable the button.
You can directly use [disabled] directive in angular.

For Example:

```
<button (click)="next($event)" [disabled]="!products || !products.hasNext">
</button>
```

Comment: I agree with the symptoms but not with the solution. Creating artifical values to workaround the problem is not ideal imho. There are 2 solutions: 1) Add `*ngIf="this.products"` on the button. 2) change the `disabled` condition to `[disabled]="!products || !products.hasNext"`

Comment: Thank you for that idea. I will update the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i didn't even think it can be so simple :) It worked perfectly